# Special characters found in logs?

Tags: malware

Whilst reviewing logs for a PC we believe to be compromised, we noticed that we had special characters in the authentication failure logs originating from the PC itself. By this I mean that the logs are originating from `PC$ȃ` or `PC$肒`. We have never seen this before. The logs *should* be originating from just the user's account. Has anyone seen this before or can help explain why it is occurring?

Comment: Perhaps someone is trying to authenticate with nonstandard/nonunicode characters, which are "lost in translation"?